# Convert an array of integers into a SymPy matrix of their ratios

Tags: python, matrix, sympy, rational-number

I'd like to change a 3D array of integers into a `SymPy` matrix of rationals. I know that I should use `Sympy` (`Rational` and `Matrix`) but I don't know how to do it.

For example,

```
[[[2, 1], [1, 3], [3, 2]], [[4, 3], [5, 2], [0, 1]]]
```

should become

```
2 1/3 3/2
4/3 5/2 0
```

A Picture of how it should look:

[image: Wanted result image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A convenient way is to [create a matrix from a function](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/matrices/matrices.html#creating-matrices) as follows:

```
from sympy import Matrix, S
a = [[[2, 1], [1, 3], [3, 2]], [[4, 3], [5, 2], [0, 1]]]
m, n = len(a), len(a[0])
b = Matrix(m, n, lambda i, j: S(a[i][j][0])/a[i][j][1])
```

The above is assuming the array is a nested Python list. If it was a NumPy 3D array, one can do

```
from sympy import Matrix, S
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[[2, 1], [1, 3], [3, 2]], [[4, 3], [5, 2], [0, 1]]])
m, n, _ = a.shape
b = Matrix(m, n, lambda i, j: S(a[i, j, 0])/a[i, j, 1])
```

Note about `S(x)/y` versus `Rational(x, y)`: the former is division preceded by converting `x` into a SymPy object. (See [SymPy numbers](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/gotchas.html#python-numbers-vs-sympy-numbers).) 
This makes a rational out of any kind of integer-looking inputs. `Rational(x, y)` is a direct construction of a Rational object, which is fine with Python integers as inputs but has an issue with `np.int64` datatype. For this reason, `Rational(a[i, j, 0], a[i, j, 1])` would not work in the second snippet. (Possibly a SymPy bug.)

Comment: I have a such fault:  unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'Integer' and 'str'

Comment: So your input array is read as _strings_. This means you need to apply S to both numerator and denominator:  `S(a[i, j, 0])/S(a[i, j, 1])`

Comment: I have problem. I'd like to change this matrix for 3D matrix now. but now S(a[i, j, 0])/S(a[i, j, 1]) is how one object. How set it